# Argument of type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<boolean, unknown>'

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Service Code -

```
private flgCityMismatch$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
flgCityMismatchVal = this.flgCityMismatch$.asObservable();

setflgCityMismatch(value: boolean) {
    this.flgCityMismatch$.next(value);
}
```

In Component, I am calling setflgCityMismatch to set the value according to the user action-

```
showProfileDetailsLink(redirectURl: string) {
    this.dataService.setflgCityMismatch(true);
    this.router.navigate([redirectURl]);
}
```

I m calling subscribe to this BehaviorSubject like below -

```
this.dataservice_mylocation.flgCityMismatchVal.subscribe(data => flgCityMismatch = data);
```

I want to unsubscribe after assigning the value. I tried -

```
let flgCityMismatch = false;
     this.dataservice_mylocation.flgCityMismatchVal
          .pipe(take(1)) // this is throwing error 
          .subscribe(data => flgCityMismatch = data);
```

But I getting below error -

```
"message": "Argument of type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<boolean, unknown>'.\n  Type 'Observable<unknown>' provides no match for the signature '(source: Observable<boolean>): Observable<unknown>'.",
```

I am using Angular 8. I don't know what is the issue. I have tried takeUntil as well but it also throws the same error.

Comment: Can you provide a StackBlitz MRE, I can not reproduce the issue.

Comment: maybe check your imports and verify that `take` is coming from `rxjs/operators`

Comment: @BizzyBob yes i have imported it from import { take } from 'rxjs/operator/take'; Addition - With the above mention error I am also receiving this error -
 "message": "The 'this' context of type 'void' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'Observable<unknown>'." Any idea what exactly i m missing to specify because I searched and tried takeUntil I get same error.

Comment: I don't know.  Try reproducing in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular-ivy)

Comment: Yeah I tried and when I removed pipe and directly called takeUntil it isn't throwing any error and worked for me. I believe there is some issue with Versions `this.dataService.flgCityMismatchVal.takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$).subscribe(data => flgCityMismatch = data);`

Comment: this is the correct import: import { take } from 'rxjs/operators'. Try with it, cause everything else seems to be correct 100%